# Writing/reading string through NetworkStream (sockets) for a chat

Tags: c#, string, sockets, chat, networkstream

Sorry if this is hard to understand, trying out C# for the first time.

I am trying to make a simple public 'chat' between clients that are connected to the server. I've tried passing integers to the server and printing them out and everything was fine, however,when I switched to   strings, it seems that it can only pass 1 character (because of `ns.Write(converted, 0, 1);`). If I increase the ns.Write to `ns.Write(converted,0,10)` everything crashes (both the client and the server) when I enter a message that is less than 10 characters.

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace MultiServeris
{
    class Multiserveris
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(1000);         
            ServerSocket.Start();                                     
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();        
                handleClient client = new handleClient();                       
                client.startClient(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    public class handleClient
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Chat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }
        private void Chat()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10]; 
            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream ns = clientSocket.GetStream();
                ns.Read(buffer,0,1);
                string line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Klientas
{
    class Klientas
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 1000);
                NetworkStream ns = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] converted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                ns.Write(converted, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A common mistake when reading from a *stream* is not checking what the *Read* method returns. (It may not match the size you want to read to)

Comment: L.B, if I change both Write and Read to, for example, (converted,0,10) it crashes.

Comment: @user43132 I already read it. But it seems you didn't read my comment carefully.

Comment: Yup I just realised what You ment. If I enter 10+ character message everything works fine. Is there some way to make it so that the read/write doesn't depend on the Write() and Read() size argument?

Comment: `var reader = new StreamReader(ns); var line = reader.ReadLine();` ?

Comment: Not sure how to correctly replace the current code with the reader.    The server doesn't print out anything with                 using 

(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns))
                {
                   string tekstas = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(tekstas);
                }

I will test it out tomorrow, thanks for the information.

Comment: @user43132 - I know this is an ancient question.  I am just curious that you've ever tried byte[] converted=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str); ns.Write(converted,0,converted.Length); //because that should work. Don't use Text.Encoding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're best using the BinaryReader/BinaryWriter classes to correctly format and read out data. This removes the need to process it yourself. For example in the client do:

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
writer.Write(str);
```

And in the server:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked instantly! Would it make sense to also use this for printing the stream on the client side? Using the server just for the threads?

Comment: BinaryWrite and BinaryReader need to be on both ends for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

When using BinaryReader or BinaryWriter on the same stream, and you have .NET framework version 4.5 or above, be sure to leave the underlying stream open by using the overload:

```
using (var w = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true)) {}
```